# Is Cython used for building C code or is it used for building Python extensions?

Tags: python, c++, c, cython

I am the sole Matlab user on a team of C++/C# developers. I am transitioning to Python, and was hoping that Cython could help me bridge the gap between my work and my colleagues' work.

I originally thought that Cython could be used to compile Python code to a C source file, which **could** then be imported/called from Python. I was hoping for two benefits from this:

1. A speed boost in my programs, and
2. A C source file that could be handed off to my colleagues for some **slight** polishing and then ultimately implemented in their (C++/C#) packages.

Unfortunately, it looks like the latter is not an option, but I'm not positive. It looks like the C source file is very bloated with lots of references to Python. I have a three-line Python script that declares a cdef char*, assigns the string "hello world!" to that variable, then prints it. The resulting C file is 2000 lines long.

So, my question is, is benefit #2 unobtainable with Cython? Is the C code generated with Cython **only intended to be used by Python**, or is there a way to remove the Python bloat and get a concise C translation of the Python code?

Comment: When you look at the info tab of [tag:cython](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cython/info) >Cython is a language for quickly generating Python C extensions.

Comment: It could be that Nuitka would be more appropriate, http://nuitka.net.  However I can't understand why you need the C.  Do you want to use a Python DLL?  When using C# with Python, Iron Python might be a better fit:  http://ironpython.net

Comment: I *think* he's saying he wants to write Python code for a C++ project, having it semiautomatically translated into equivalent standalone C or C++ code.  If that's indeed the objective, then I have three words: no, no, and no.

Comment: You can call Cython from C/C++ http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c. However it tends to retain a dependency on libpython (unless you're very careful to keep things as simple and typed as possible)

Comment: You could argue that cython is a better source language than C++/C# (less code, lots of libs, etc...) and those other programmers should consider it as a way to get to market faster. You could also try pushing a large boulder up a hill which is likely easier.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - That was my intent/hope. Given the answer below and the reaction here in the comments, I'll stop trying to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Cython's output is not intended for human consumption

Cython treats C as an intermediate language, in much the same way as LLVM treats LLVM IR as an intermediate language.  Cython's purpose is to produce *Python extension modules*, and C is just the most reasonable means to that end.  It will generally produce a maze of twisty little preprocessor directives, all totally unreadable.  You should not use Cython if you want C code that you can read.